# Bash not resolving variable

Tags: bash

Very new to bash. I'm trying to write a file which simplifies running an sshuttle command to one of a list of environments.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A environments

environments=(
    [dev]="dev.myhost.com 10.0.1.0/22 --dns"
    [qa]="qa.myhost.com 10.0.2.0/22 --dns"
    [prod]="prod.myhost.com 10.0.3.0/22 --dns"
)

vpn() {
    echo sshuttle --verbose -r ${environments[$1]}
    sshuttle --verbose -r ${environments[$1]}
}
```

The usage will be `vpn qa`, which should resolve to `sshuttle --verbose -r qa.myhost.com 10.0.2.0/22 --dns`

Unfortunately, when running `vpn qa` I get instead an error which indicates that the `${environments[$1]}` isn't being resolved at runtime:

```
usage: sshuttle [-l [ip:]port] -r [user@]sshserver[:port] <subnets...>
sshuttle: error: at least one subnet, subnet file, or -N expected
```

The echo outputs what I am expecting to see, and copy-pasting that into the terminal works.

What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: How did you run this function? Script|function args issue?

Comment: @Ivan I ran `source ./sshuttle_vpn.sh` to source the bash file. Then simply `vpn qa` on the terminal. The echo displays the command as it should run.

Comment: And your shell is bash?

Comment: @EricP Please also pay attention to the synopsis, due to the manual https://sshuttle.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manpage.html#synopsis I'd suggest moving the `--dns`  option from `[qa]="qa.myhost.com 10.0.2.0/22 --dns"` to somewhere 


before `-r ${environments[$1]}` in the command.

Comment: @Vab, moving the --dns to before the -r made no difference

Comment: @Ivan no, it's zsh, but a) the script has a shebang at the start and b) the sshuttle command that is output in the echo runs perfectly when copied and pasted back into the terminal.

Comment: @EricP, maybe it is worth opening a `bash` session from your `zsh` and running the  command that is output in the echo to see if it will run successfully?

Comment: @EricP `$ source --help
source: source filename [arguments]
    Execute commands from a file in the current shell. ...` shebang is ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

zsh doesn't perform word-splitting on unquoted variable references like most other shells do. That means that when `${environments[$1]}` expands to `qa.myhost.com 10.0.2.0/22 --dns`, that value will be treated as a single long argument (containing spaces) rather than as three separate arguments. The difference is not visible with `echo`, since that just puts spaces between separate arguments, but it matters a great deal to `sshuttle`. (This is yet another case where `echo` is misleading, and using `set -x` to show what's going on would be much better.)

In order to get zsh to split the value, you need to add an `=` modifier to the variable reference: `${=environments[$1]}`. Of course, that's not compatible with bash, so if you want this to work in both bash and zsh, you need to do something like this:

```
environments=(
    [dev]="dev.myhost.com 10.0.1.0/22 --dns"
    [qa]="qa.myhost.com 10.0.2.0/22 --dns"
    [prod]="prod.myhost.com 10.0.3.0/22 --dns"
)

if [[ -n "$ZSH_VERSION" ]]; then
    # zsh-compatible definition of the function
    vpn() {
        echo sshuttle --verbose -r ${=environments[$1]}
        sshuttle --verbose -r ${=environments[$1]}
    }
else
    # bash-compatible definition of the function
    vpn() {
        echo sshuttle --verbose -r ${environments[$1]}
        sshuttle --verbose -r ${environments[$1]}
    }
fi
```

Note that the `#!/bin/bash` in your script is ignored (and misleading) -- since you're `source`ing it, it runs in the shell you `source`d it from, whether that's bash, zsh, dash, or whatever.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, this worked perfectly.